# Redirect BIAR Import On Buisness Objects

Tags: business-objects

On my development server we have several subfolders representing different releases.

Root
 
    |-R1
    |-R2

My QA server is dedicated to R1. I want to promote all the reports and universes in R1 to the Root of QA.

I do the BIAR export and it stores the R1 path and tries to put all the contents into an R1 folder on QA.  I want to redirect that import to the root of QA.

Possible?  Using BusinessObjects XI 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without some hacking.

1. Export the content to a BIAR file
2. Rename the BIAR file from .biar to .zip
3. Open the archive, and extract businessobjects.xml
4. Modify businessobjects.xml to change the parent CUIDs of the objects that you want located in a different folder.
5. Repackage the zip, rename it back to .biar, and import.

Obviously you'd want to do a fair amount of testing with the method before doing it in a live environment...

Answer (score 0):

As Joe said, this isn't possible without changing the metadata (the XML file) that resides in the BIAR archive.

Is there any reason why you wouldn't just want to import the R1 folder into QA and then move its contents to the root? It will save you quite some time not having to hack the XML and it'll be a lot less error prone.